# Python not retrieving stdout from subprocess Popen exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, subprocess, stdout

I know there is a lot similar question out there but I really can't figure out what am I doing wrong.
The thing I'm trying to accomplish is: To read the `stdout` from an `.exe` file previously compiled from a `.py`.

**This is the main program to execute the subprocess**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


runcloud = Popen([r'demo2.exe'], stdout=PIPE)
with runcloud.stdout:
    for line in iter(runcloud.stdout.readline, b''):
        print(line)  ##PRINTS NOTHING ??
```

**And this is the .exe file before compiling (demo2.exe)**

```
import os

try:
    print('RESPONSE')
except:
    print('no connection')

os._exit(0)
```

For some implementation, I need to compile the `demo2` and add the last line of `os._exit()`
. Tho this `.exe` file when run in cmd it does show the printing string. But fail to print from the main program using `subprocess`

---

**EDIT:**
*After some comments, I ran the code without compiling the file, and adding the keyword `python`, and still printing nothing.
Comment: Even if I let it run with the py file or just remove the `os._exit(0)`, It still prints nothing, Note that there is no other file with similar name in my directory.*

---

**EDIT - WORKAROUND:** After something finding the solution for hours, the only workaround was to write a code inside the `exe` file that saves (I don't think I can call this as 'redirect') the outputs on another file like `.txt` or a easy setup database like `SQlite`, then in the main program call `Popen` to execute the `exe` with the `.wait()` and finishing up by reading the written values on the file or database.
**Since I haven't find out why `Popen` is not capturing `print` functions in the `stdout` and the workaround can be found in other questions already, I'll just leave this question open for now.**

Comment: Note that you can just use ``for line in runcloud.stdout:``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi still nothing printing

Comment: After minor corrections to make this example runnable (changing ``demo.exe`` to ``./demo2.py``), I cannot reproduce this problem. How do you compile the file? Does it work when the file is not compiled? Since the executable is specified without path, are you sure you are running the correct ``demo2.exe``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Sorry, I forgot the python keyword, ok so i ran it as with py file. It still prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should put a path to the demo2.exe, i.e. your string should be `r'./demo2.exe'` if the exe is in the same directory as the main program (or a full path if it's not). Then, try removing the os._exit(0) call from your demo2 file. You can also try using subprocess check_output for this type of call, it simplifies the code a bit:

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output([r'./demo2'])
print(output)
```

Comment: the `os._exit(0)` is needed as I am implementing `python-firebase` module, when compiled the app will keep rebooting itself until the pc crashes, this stops the program right on the first call.

Comment: Well, I tried your code, and it printed `b''`, Even if I remove the `os._exit()`, it still prints nothing. I don't get the reason why.

Comment: Yes, I update everything, I was able to make a workaround but couldn't figure out why sub process is not reading print function as stdout